# Why does these extra lines of code cause the "Towers of Hanoi" number of moves to increase?

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

My lecturer asked us the following in a test:

"*Given the following code:*

```
int count=0;
static void towersOfhanoi(int n, char source, char target, char spare)
    {    
        count++;
        if (n==1)
            System.out.println("move a disk from "+source+" to "+target);
         else
         {  
            towersOfhanoi(n-1, source, spare, target); 

            System.out.println("move a disk from "+source+" to "+target);

            towersOfhanoi(n-1, spare, target, source); 
            towersOfhanoi(1, spare, source, target); 
            towersOfhanoi(n-1, source, spare, target);
```

*What are the value of moves after towersofhanoi(11, A,B,C) has been executed?"*

I went home and programmed this and the number of moves have increased, before I plugged these lines of code, I'll call it **A** (using 11 disks, produced 118097 moves!) :

```
            towersOfhanoi(n-1, spare, target, source); 
            towersOfhanoi(1, spare, source, target); 
            towersOfhanoi(n-1, source, spare, target);
```

I had these lines of code in its place before I plugged those in. I'll call it **B** (using 11 disks, produced 2047 moves) :

```
            towersOfhanoi(n-1, spare, target, source);
```

My question is, what did the 3 lines of code do in **A**? Why did the number of moves change, and is there a formula to work out the number of moves? I know that the amount of moves can be worked out using "(2^11) -1" for **B**. Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Okay I will try my best. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the **B** line is the correct solution for a Tower of Hanoi problem. The three lines of **A** instead of **B** do exactly what they say they do: they call the function recursively with those arguments. The first line is the same of **B**, so that is correct. The other two lines do not make sense in terms of the problem. You put them in there, so the question is more: why did you do that?

I am guessing that you wanted to do the following instead:

```
   if (n==1) {
        System.out.println("move a disk from "+source+" to "+target);
   } else {
        towersOfhanoi(n-1, source, spare, target); 
        towersOfhanoi(1, source, target, spare); 
        towersOfhanoi(n-1, spare, target, source); 
   }
```

Which would another correct expression of the Towers of Hanoi problem, with the same number of moves as the original **B**.

As for formulas: if we define the number of moves for n disks as N(n), then original solution solution as the number of moves (following the source code):

```
N(n) = N(n-1) + 1 + N(n-1) 
     = 2 * N(n-1) + 1
     = 2 * (2 * (2 * ... (2 * 1 + 1) ... + 1) + 1) + 1)
     = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-3) + ... + 1
     = (1 - 2^n) / (1 - 2)
     = 2^n - 1
```

Along a similar reasoning for your A code:

```
N(n) = N(n-1) + 1 + N(n-1) + 1 + N(n-1)
     = 3 * N(n-1) + 2
     = 3^(n-1) + 2 * (3^(n-2) + ... + 1)
     = 3^(n-1) + 2 * (1-3^(n-1)) / (1-3)
     = 2 * 3^(n-1) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have typed that whole 3 lines wrong I guess!